# How to initialise a complex C struct in one line?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I have a structure:

```
typedef struct stock {
  const char* key1p2;    // stock code
  const char* key2p2;    // short desc
  const char* desc1;     // description
  const char* prod_grp;  // product group
  const char dp_inqty;   // decimal places in quantity
  const long salprc_u;   // VAT excl price
  const long salprc_e;   // VAT includive price
  const long b_each;     // quantity in stock
  const long b_alloc;    // allocated qty
  const char* smsgr_id;  // subgroup
  const char** barcodes; // barcodes
} stock_t;
```

and I want to initialise arrays of instances of this structure, in one line of code per stock struct.

I have tried:

```
stock_t data_stock[] = {
    { "0001", "Soup",  "Tomato Soup",     "71", 0, 100, 120, 10, 0, "",   {"12345", "23456", NULL} },
    { "0002", "Melon", "Melon and Ham",   "71", 0, 200, 240, 10, 0, "",   {"34567", "45678", NULL} },
    ...
    { NULL,   NULL,    NULL,              NULL, 0,   0,   0,  0, 0, NULL, NULL         }
};
```

but it fails with:

```
data.c:26:74: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char **' with an expression of type 'char [6]'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  { "0001", "Soup",  "Tomato Soup",     "71", 0, 100, 120, 10, 0, "",   {"12345", "23456", NULL} },
                                                                         ^~~~~~~
```

It is the barcode field which is problematic, as it is char**.

(that was clang, but GCC reports a similar error, but less helpfully.)

It's almost as if the compiler has ignored the curly brace before "12345".

I can work around the problem using:

```
const char *barcodes0001[] = {"12345", "23456", NULL};

stock_t data_stock[] = {
  { "0001", "Soup",  "Tomato Soup",     "71", 0, 100, 120, 10, 0, "",   barcodes0001 },
```

Is the cause of this problem a different between char *[] and char **, or is there something more subtle.  (Perhaps you can initialise arrays of structs, but not structs of arrays.)

Comment: It seems that stock data is something that would change frequently. May I ask why you're storing this in static structures instead of a file or database?

Comment: I guess you can't write `const char* barcodes[3]`?

Comment: @Dark Falcon - this is just an interesting little problem which I came across while mocking up some stub code which will be replaced by a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid to have to declare a named dummy variable you can use a *compound literal*

```
stock_t data_stock[] = {
    { "0001", "Soup",  "Tomato Soup",     "71", 0, 100, 120, 10, 0, "",   (const char*[]){"12345", "23456", NULL} },
    { "0002", "Melon", "Melon and Ham",   "71", 0, 200, 240, 10, 0, "",   (const char*[]){"34567", "45678", NULL} },
    ...
    { NULL,   NULL,    NULL,              NULL, 0,   0,   0,  0, 0, NULL, NULL         }
};
```

This is a way to define a local temporary variable with a syntax of `(type){ initializers }` which is available since c99 (and clang and gcc have them).

*Edit:* The lifetime of these compound literals is the same as your variable `data_stock` so I suppose this is ok. In any case I think you should mark most of your fields also as `const`, e.g `const char*const key1p2;`

Also it would be much easier to read if you'd use *designated initializers* something like

```
{ .keyp1 = "0001", ... }
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not as if the compiler is *ignoring* your brace, it's as if your brace is ignoring the syntax rules of the language, rather. :)

The field `barcode` is a single pointer (to a pointer, but that's beside the point). You need to provide a valid pointer value, and the braced thing you're providing doesn't match.

You also can't do this:

```
struct foo {
  int a, b;
};

struct foo *pointer_to_foo = &{ 1, 2 }; /* Not valid code. */
```

Which is logically the same as what you're trying to do. Or, removing the `struct`, you also can't do this:

```
int *pointer_to_a = &12; /* Not valid code. */
```

The solution where you've broken out the `barcode` data is the way to do it.

Comment: but you don't really give a solution :(

Comment: Thanks, this really gets to the heart of the issue, but Jens' answer is something I can use.